# c# xpath with an OR

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<users>
 <user>
  <location>ny</location>
  <status>1</status>
 </user>
 <user>
  <location>nj</location>
  <status>1</status>
 </user>
 <user>
  <location>pa</location>
  <status>50</status>
 </user>
</users>
```

What I actually need is all users in ny or nj who also have a status of 1.

Based on the previous answers and some additional Googling I came up with:

```
/users/user[location='ny' and status='1']|/users/user[location='nj' and status='1'
```

Is there a less verbose to write this? i.e. more along the lines of:

```
/users/user[location='ny' | 'pa']  and /users/user[status='1']
```

Answer (score 3):

The XPath you're looking for is:

```
/users/user[location='ny']|/users/user[status='1']
```

You can test it here:

http://www.futurelab.ch/xmlkurs/xpath.en.html

PS: Your XML above is incorrect (status is incorrectly closed with a height tag)

Comment: XPath for the second version of the question: /users/user[(location='ny' or location='nj') and status=1]

Answer (score 1):

The following would also work:

```
    /users/user[location='ny' | status='1']
```

Answer (score 0):

//user[location='ny' | status='1']
//.[location='ny' | status='1']”

I'd have made location and status as attributes of  and fished for those instead.  They're just wasting space as they are.  Also, consider  for your text if you keep the current structure.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
  /users/user[(location='ny' or location='nj') and (status = '1') ]
```

I don't think '|' is valid in predicate, as it represents union expression in XPath syntax